# Post JSON data to web server in vb.net using JSON.Net

Tags: json, vb.net, json.net

I am trying to post data in JSON form to a web site, but no matter what I do, I get a 500 Internal Error.

The string I aim to create is something like that : {"orders":[{"id":"7","invoice_number":"1007"},{"id":"8","invoice_number":"1008"},{"id":"11","invoice_number":"1011"}]} , which I can easily get with JSON.net

The webmaster of the site sent me this command in order to post data

```
curl -vvvvvvvv "http://staging.voltige2001.net/fr/api/update-orders" --data '{"orders":[{"id":"7","invoice_number":"1007"},{"id":"8","invoice_number":"1008"},{"id":"11","invoice_number":"1011"}]}' -X PATCH
```

But I don't know what is curl and how this differs from what I am doing.

Here is the code I have :

```
    Dim strInvNumber As String

    If Not IsNothing(oDsFacture) AndAlso oDsFacture.Tables.Count > 0 AndAlso oDsFacture.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
        strInvNumber = oDsFacture.Tables(0).Rows(0)("No_Facture")
    Else
        strInvNumber = "9999" ' Pas de facture
    End If

    Dim oOrder As New Confirmation.Order With {.ID = oCommande.ID, .InvoiceNumber = strInvNumber}

    Dim oConfirmation As New Confirmation With {.Orders = New List(Of Confirmation.Order) From {oOrder}}
    Dim strResponse As String = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(oConfirmation)

    Dim data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strResponse)


    Dim req As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create(_ResponseURL)
    req.ContentType = "application/json"
    req.Method = "POST"
    'req.ContentLength = strResponse.Length

    Using oStream As New StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream)
        oStream.Write(strResponse)
        oStream.Flush()
        oStream.Close()
    End Using

    Try
        Dim response As HttpWebResponse = req.GetResponse
        Using oSReader As New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream)

        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
```

Here is the class I use to convert to JSON

```
Public Class Confirmation


Public Class Order
    <JsonProperty("id")> Public Property ID As String
    <JsonProperty("invoice_number")> Public Property InvoiceNumber As String
        End Class

<JsonProperty("orders")> Public Property Orders As List(Of Order)
End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

curl is a command-line tool to transfer network data. Here's the man page: [man.cx/curl](http://man.cx/curl).

The -X option in the curl example you were given means to use something other than GET. In this case, they are expecting PATCH. Try `req.Method = PATCH`.

I haven't run into the PATCH method before, the [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789) summary makes it sound like an HTTP upsert:

> The PATCH method requests that a set of changes described in the
> request entity be applied to the resource identified by the Request-
> URI.  The set of changes is represented in a format called a "patch
> document" identified by a media type.  If the Request-URI does not
> point to an existing resource, the server MAY create a new resource,
> depending on the patch document type (whether it can logically modify
> a null resource) and permissions, etc.

Comment: That's probably it. I get another error now, but it seems more like a firewall that is posing problem, which is none of my concern.